# EACCES that should not happen

Tags: permissions, rhel, apache-httpd

I have a situation on a Linux machine that I can't really explain.

Some background: We're running apache with a c/c++ module that forwards requests to our application. It does so by reading a .port file which specifies a local port to send the requests to.

After installation, it is not possible to connect using the web interface. After a bit of troubleshooting I bring out strace and see that the apache processes fail to read the .port file:

```
[pid  8105] stat("/tmp/somedir/application.port", 0x7ffff9694470) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I check the permissions on the file:

```
% ls -l /tmp/somedir/application.port
-rw-r--r--. 1 appuser staff    5 Oct 16 14:10 application.port
```

So, anyone should be able to read that, right?

I check who the apache process runs as:

```
% ps -ef | grep 8105
appuser   8105  3357  0 15:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

So the apache process runs as the owner of the file. That should work too, right?

Finally, I do:

```
% su - appuser
% stat /tmp/somedir/application.port
  File: `/tmp/somedir/application.port'
  Size: 5           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 11h/17d Inode: 1400293     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/ appuser)   Gid: ( 1001/   staff)
Access: 2013-10-16 14:10:03.357679902 +0200
Modify: 2013-10-16 14:10:03.357679902 +0200
Change: 2013-10-16 14:10:03.357679902 +0200
```

So, the "appuser" owns the file, runs the web server, but don't have the permission to do stat() on it from within the web server process? 
Does anyone have an idea about what could be going on here?

I should also mention that this is not the first installation we've done, and the others work as expected. There might have been some manual fiddling during the installation of this particular machine, but I still don't see how we can end up like this.

Restarting processes also does nothing to change the behavior.

The machine is a RHEL 6 box.

Comment: `ls -lZ` to check SELinux? `ls -ld /tmp/somedir`?

Comment: @Mikel SELinux is a good suggestion. Is is a bit of an unknown area to me, but I'll look in to that, thanks.

Comment: @MattiasNilsson also see `stat(2)` man page: *`EACCES` Search  permission is denied for one of the directories in the path prefix of path. (See also path_resolution(7).)*

Comment: @peterph That would be a good guess but it's contradicted by `stat /tmp/somedir/application.port` working. Since `stat` can access the file but not Apache, there's some security framework at play (SELinux presumably since this is RHEL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it turned out that the problem was indeed SELinux-related.

For anyone else who might need to get a quick understanding of what SELinux is and some useful commands, I recommend the [SELinux for mere mortals](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQqX3RWn0Yw) youtube video. It's a great introduction to get started with troubleshooting.

Comment: +1 self-answers are good for StackExchange. I'm glad you found the fix (and my one complaint about SELinux is that it hides itself unless you know to ask about it (what do you mean you don't know `ls -Z`??? ;) )